# Selecting distinct notifications and prepare a clearer notification message

Tags: php, mysql

I have created a notification system and it's pretty good. There are a few things that need to be worked on to make it perfect - so here I am.

The application I'm working on is a website written in PHP.

My notifications have this `seen` column which indicates if the notification was checked out or not. This column gets updated when an user click on the notification dropdown button which is pretty similar to Facebook's.

There are a few occasions when there are two identical notifications - Same user to same target (URL). I want notifications to be selected in an unique way and the identical ones to be ignored. I can't even understand how those identical ones are being stored in the first place.

Anyway, here's a sample output array of notifications:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [notification_id] => 34
            [receiver_id] => 9
            [notification_issuer] => 11
            [notification_message] => Dugipo has liked your image
            [notification_target] => http://localhost/imgzer/image/v2M6S2V1J3h7
            [notification_type] => like
            [notification_time] => 1391291043
            [notification_seen] => 1
            [user_avatar] => 
            [username] => Dugipo
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [notification_id] => 33
            [receiver_id] => 9
            [notification_issuer] => 11
            [notification_message] => Dugipo has liked your image
            [notification_target] => http://localhost/imgzer/image/v2M6S2V1J3h7
            [notification_type] => like
            [notification_time] => 1391288815
            [notification_seen] => 1
            [user_avatar] => 
            [username] => Dugipo
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [notification_id] => 32
            [receiver_id] => 9
            [notification_issuer] => 11
            [notification_message] => Dugipo has liked your comment
            [notification_target] => http://localhost/imgzer/image/o3F6g8b8t6Q0#cid-64
            [notification_type] => like
            [notification_time] => 1391216243
            [notification_seen] => 1
            [user_avatar] => 
            [username] => Dugipo
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [notification_id] => 31
            [receiver_id] => 9
            [notification_issuer] => 11
            [notification_message] => Dugipo has liked your image
            [notification_target] => http://localhost/imgzer/image/o3F6g8b8t6Q0
            [notification_type] => like
            [notification_time] => 1391216135
            [notification_seen] => 1
            [user_avatar] => 
            [username] => Dugipo
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [notification_id] => 30
            [receiver_id] => 9
            [notification_issuer] => 11
            [notification_message] => Dugipo has liked your image
            [notification_target] => http://localhost/imgzer/image/o3F6g8b8t6Q0
            [notification_type] => like
            [notification_time] => 1391214642
            [notification_seen] => 1
            [user_avatar] => 
            [username] => Dugipo
        )

)
```

As you can see, there are 2 pairs of identical arrays and that's not what I'm after. I'm also trying to achieve the effect when two or more people liked the same thing, the messages become like: ***X, Y and n others have liked your image***

I'm can't think on how I'd do this. Anyway, this is the function/method that collects the notifications:

```
public function getNotifications($seen = false)
{
    global $db;

    $seen = ($seen === true) ? 1 : 0;
    $limit = ($seen === true) ? 5 : 10;

    $sql = 'SELECT n.*, u.user_avatar, u.username FROM ' . NOTIFICATIONS_TABLE . ' n 
        LEFT JOIN ' . USERS_TABLE . " u 
            ON n.notification_issuer = u.user_id
        WHERE receiver_id = ? 
            AND notification_seen = $seen 
        ORDER BY notification_time DESC 
        LIMIT 5";   
    $query = $db->prepare($sql);
    $query->execute(array($this->id));

    $result = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    /*for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($result); $i++)
    {
        if ($result[$i]['notification_message'] == $result[++$i]['notification_message'])
        {
            $new_message = '';

            if ($result[$i]['notification_issuer'] != $result[++$i]['notification_issuer'])
            {
                $new_message .= '';
            }
        }
    }*/

    return $result;
}
```

The commented `for` loop was meant to create that effect where the people who liked a certain thing become a single notification and the names get separated by a comma and an "and" for the n other people who liked the image.

This is the function/method that stores the notifications:

```
public function sendNotification($notification, $receiver, $notification_target = null, $notification_type = 'default')
{
    global $db;

    $sql = 'INSERT INTO ' . NOTIFICATIONS_TABLE . '(receiver_id, notification_issuer, notification_message, notification_target, notification_type, notification_time) 
        VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)';
    $query = $db->prepare($sql);
    $query->execute(array($receiver, $this->id, $notification, $notification_target, $notification_type, time()));  
}
```

Example use of this method:

```
// Send notification / Make sure that the notification sender isn't the same user that's going to receive the notification
if ($user->get_data('user_id') != $this->image_uploader_id)
{
    $user->sendNotification(
        sprintf('<strong>%s</strong> has liked your image', $user->get_data('username')), 
        $this->image_uploader_id, 
        self::convert('name2url', $this->image_name),
        'like'
    );
}
```

---

Lastly, here's the schema of the notifications table:

```
+----------------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field                | Type                | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| notification_id      | int(11) unsigned    | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| receiver_id          | int(11) unsigned    | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| notification_issuer  | int(11) unsigned    | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| notification_message | varchar(255)        | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| notification_target  | varchar(255)        | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| notification_type    | varchar(55)         | NO   |     | default |                |
| notification_time    | int(11) unsigned    | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| notification_seen    | tinyint(1) unsigned | NO   |     | 0       |                |
+----------------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

**SQL Fiddle:** http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6970b/1

---

So I'm basically after two things here:

1. <strike>Be able to select unique rows. Repeated rows get ignored</strike>
2. Achieve the effect to merge notifications that have the same target to one notification which then shows the names of the persons of the same action (ie. liking) like this: *X, Y, Z and n others liked your image.*

So after a `SELECT` from the database, I'd like to have all users that that created a notification for the same target, become a nicely readable string like I've described it above. I'm trying to avoid users that liked/disliked/commented on the same target to have a separate notification to the receiver - they should concatenate somehow.

So lets say the action is *image_like*. Five users *image_like-d* the same `notification_target` or now we can identify what the user will get notified about with `notification_type` (which will be *image_like*) and `reference_id` (we'll know it will be an image now); So now we have complete knowledge what **image_id** is liked based on `reference_id` and we also know it's an image because the `notification_type` says **image**_like.

So with this table:

```
id    reference    target     issuer_id    type
1     25           tg1        43           like
2     25           tg1        23           like
3     53           tg2        77           comment
4     53           tg2        23           comment
5     53           tg2        67           comment
6     53           tg2        98           dislike
7     34           tg3        65           like
```

From this table, this would be the results:

- User43 **and** User23 liked reference25 (links to tg1)
- User77, User23 **and** User67 commented on reference 53 (links to tg2)
- User98 disliked reference53 (links to tg2)
- User65 liked reference34 (links to tg3)

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: About the similar notifications, it seems that the problem is in the function the adds the notification to database.

Comment: I've provided that one too now.

Comment: Can you also show the usage of that function? Maybe you're calling the `sendNotification` function twice or something like that.

Comment: I call this method inside different other methods. For example when someone likes something, I add this method at the end of the `like` method. Same goes for dislike, favorite etc.

Comment: You can achive this by using [GROUP_CONCAT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) and [DISTINCT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/distinct-optimization.html). Provide a www.sqlfiddle.com link with sample data.

Comment: GROUP_CONCAT would do the job, allowing you to eliminate duplicates and group up the different people who have a relevant notification. Only issue is what you want to do with notification times, etc, which do still vary (or do you just ignore those fields anyway)?

Comment: Try somthing like this 
`SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT notification_id),
GROUP_CONCAT(receiver_id),
GROUP_CONCAT(notification_issuer),
GROUP_CONCAT(notification_message),
GROUP_CONCAT(notification_target),
GROUP_CONCAT(notification_type),
GROUP_CONCAT(notification_time),
GROUP_CONCAT(notification_seen),
GROUP_CONCAT(u.user_avatar),
GROUP_CONCAT(u.username),
FROM
notifications n
LEFT JOIN 
users u
ON
n.notification_issuer = u.user_id
WHERE
receiver_id = ? 
AND notification_seen = ?
GROUP BY notification_type
ORDER BY notification_time DESC 
LIMIT 5`

Comment: @Kickstart The time is just there. I tend to store the time for each new row I create even though I might not actually use it somewhere.

Comment: SQL Fiddle added as requested. Thanks for the support.

Comment: But when you extract the details you have duplicate notifications for the same person / event, but with a different time. When you get the details of a notification do you want all the times for a duplicate notification, none of them, the latest one, or a random one? For example, with your original example with 5 notifications, exactly what do you want returned?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am sharing only the query part which solves your first and second requirements assuming that your data remains in the same structure. You can add the joins and other necessary details in your query.

`SELECT 
myView.*,
CONCAT(REPLACE(REPLACE(group_concat(SUBSTRING(notification_message,9)),'</strong>',''),SUBSTRING_INDEX(notification_message,'>',-1),''), SUBSTRING_INDEX(notification_message,'>',-1))  AS Message

FROM
(SELECT DISTINCT 
receiver_id,
notification_issuer,
notification_message,
notification_target,
notification_type 
FROM imgzer_notifications

WHERE receiver_id = 9 and notification_seen = 1 
ORDER BY notification_time DESC) myView
GROUP BY myView.receiver_id, myView.notification_target, myView.notification_type;`

I know the String functions looks complicated, but to arrive at your required output, had to play around with the Strings generated. I have modified your data set in the SQL Fiddle a little to check my output. You can do the same at:

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/70a937/49

Let me know in case there is some other criteria that is to be met or any enhancement you require in the query.

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot for your answer. Could you show me how to select additional data exactly? I need everything I've included in the original query plus the formed strings which you've already achieved.

Comment: I also would like to achieve the _x, y and n others have liked your image_ if the count of usernames is too big. I doubt this can be achieved with pure SQL though - I'm trying to apply your solution.

Comment: What additional data do you need? Were you able to apply the SQL for image notification?

Answer (score 3):

Making a lot of assumptions about your data, something like this:-

```
public function getNotifications($seen = false)
{
    global $db;
    $new_message = '';

    $seen = ($seen === true) ? 1 : 0;
    $limit = ($seen === true) ? 5 : 10;

    $sql = 'SELECT n.receiver_id, n.notification_type, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT_WS(':', u.username, u.user_avatar)) AS msgs, MAX(n.notification_time) AS LatestTime
            FROM ' . NOTIFICATIONS_TABLE . ' n
            LEFT OUTER JOIN' . USERS_TABLE . " u
            ON n.notification_issuer = u.user_id
            WHERE receiver_id = ? 
            AND notification_seen = $seen
            GROUP BY n.receiver_id, n.notification_type
            ORDER BY LatestTime DESC
            LIMIT $limit";   
    $query = $db->prepare($sql);
    $query->execute(array($this->id));

    while ($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM, PDO::FETCH_ORI_NEXT)) 
    {
        $notif = explode(',', $row['msgs']);
        switch (count($notif))
        {
            case 0 :
                // Should never happen
                break;
            case 1 :
                $aNotif = explode(":", $notif[0]);
                $new_message .= "<img='".$aNotif[1]."' />".$aNotif[0]." has ".$row['notification_type']." your event.";
                break;
            default :
                foreach($notif AS $key=>$oneNotif)
                {
                    $aNotif = explode(":", $oneNotif);
                    switch ($key)
                    {
                        case 0:
                            $new_message .= "<img='".$aNotif[1]."' />".$aNotif[0];
                            break;
                        case (count($notif) - 1):
                            $new_message .= " and <img='".$aNotif[1]."' />".$aNotif[0];
                            break;
                        default:
                            $new_message .= ", <img='".$aNotif[1]."' />".$aNotif[0];
                            break;
                    }
                }
                $new_message .= " has ".$row['notification_type']." your event by ".$row['LatestTime'].".";
                break;
        }
    }

    return $new_message;
}
```

Problem is that the time of the notification is not used (not sure where I would use the latest one), not sure what you want to do with the images (I guessed but probably wrong), and a few other minor bits.

EDIT

SQL for what I think you now want.

This is getting you all the notifications (for a receiver and whether seen or not seen), for the last 5 references to have a notification.

```
SELECT n.reference_id, GROUP_CONCAT(n.notification_message) AS msgs
FROM ' . NOTIFICATIONS_TABLE . ' n
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT receiver_id, notification_seen, reference_id, notification_issuer, MAX(notification_time) as max_notification_time
    FROM ' . NOTIFICATIONS_TABLE . '
    WHERE receiver_id = ? 
    AND notification_seen = ?
    GROUP BY receiver_id, notification_seen, reference_id, notification_issuer
) Sub1
ON n.receiver_id = Sub1.receiver_id
AND nnotification_seen = Sub1.notification_seen
AND n.reference_id = Sub1.reference_id
AND n.notification_issuer = Sub1.notification_issuer
AND n.notification_time = Sub1.max_notification_time
GROUP BY n.reference_id
ORDER BY reference_id, notification_time DESC
LIMIT $limit
```

EDIT again

Using your last updated data then this SQL would do it:-

```
SELECT n.receiver_id, n.reference_id, n.notification_type, CONCAT_WS(' ', GROUP_CONCAT(u.user_name), n.notification_type, n.reference_id) AS msgs, MAX(max_notification_id)  as max_max_notification_id
FROM imgzer_notifications n
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT receiver_id, reference_id, notification_issuer, notification_type, MAX(notification_id) as max_notification_id
    FROM imgzer_notifications
    WHERE receiver_id = ? 
    AND notification_seen = ?
    GROUP BY receiver_id, reference_id, notification_issuer, notification_type
) Sub1
ON n.receiver_id = Sub1.receiver_id
AND n.reference_id = Sub1.reference_id
AND n.notification_issuer = Sub1.notification_issuer
AND n.notification_id = Sub1.max_notification_id
AND n.notification_type = Sub1.notification_type
INNER JOIN imgzer_users u
ON n.notification_issuer = u.user_id
GROUP BY receiver_id, n.reference_id, n.notification_type
ORDER BY max_max_notification_id DESC
LIMIT $limit
```

The message is a mess though (the last comma between notification issuers isn't replaced with an and, and it should change 'like' to 'liked', etc).

What this is doing is getting the latest notification for each notification issuer for each reference. Then joins that back against notifications to get the rest of the details and uses GROUP_CONCAT to merge them into one string for a particular reference and notification type. CONCAT_WS is used to add on the notification type and any constant text, and it is ordered by the highest max notification id descending from the sub query. This way it is references / notification types that have the latest notification that are listed first (even if some of the notification in that message are not that recent).

SQL fiddle for this set up here:-

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4d876/1

Comment: In response to the last comment by you in the question comment section: I am very certain that the duplicate notifications come from liking, unliking then liking the image again. When an user unlikes an image, I'm unable to determine which notification corresponds to this like, unless I start to store a `like_id` for example which would become too much, imo. So multiple rows by the same user on the same target appear on a different time. Could you briefly explain what the code above does? I'm not sure how `GROUP_CONCAT` works and what it might return.

Comment: GROUP_CONCAT is an aggregate field, and concatenates text fields that are grouped together. In the above code for each receiver id / notification type it is bringing back all the contents of the field inside the brackets of the GROUP_CONCAT, separated by a comma. In this case I have used DISTINCT to remove duplicates, and also used CONCAT_WS to merge the user name and user avatar. However I am unsure whether you want these all together with the latest time for all users, or whether you just want to ignore duplicates for a user (in which case how do you know an unlike goes with a like).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. I'll be using a new approach for the like/unlike situation by updating the notifications table schema and adding a new field named `reference_id` for example. This is where I'll store the relevant ID for each action, so if there's a notification for a like, I'll store the like ID. This way I'll have it easy to remove the unneeded notification ID if an user unliked something. I guess this would work - I'll post an updated schema shortly.

Comment: Alright, I have updated the SQL Fiddle with a new column named `reference_id`. What this does is store the ID of the object/thing that's receiving the notification, so if an image is liked, the **image_id** is stored or when a comment is disliked, the **comment_id** is stored and so on. So when the opposite of this action happens (user removes the like for an image/comment/something else), the notification bound with it goes as well. This way it's pretty sure that duplicate notifications with the same target but different time wont happen. Having this done, does your solution still apply?

Comment: I have added some more code. However I am not exactly sure on what you want. Could you amend your original question with sample data (including when someone has liked / disliked / reliked the same reference) and the output that you would want to go with that.

Comment: Updated with a few scenarios and a new sample table.

Comment: Added a suggestion based on that (although tried to use the original column names).

Comment: So the query by itself should be enough for everything, right? Great! Thanks a lot. I'll try to refine those message strings via PHP. I'm also gonna need to select more columns... Do I simply add the column names like in a normal query (I'm not used to see such advanced queries)? Final question: What is `max_max_notification_id`?

Comment: You should also add them to the GROUP_BY query. Depends where they are coming from though.

Comment: I need to select everything from the notifications table, that's pretty important in my case. I didn't show the exact usage how it is now, but I use a lot of stuff that wasn't selected from the query you provided. I also need to select other stuff from the additional table (imgzer_users) as I've shown in the original query - that's pretty vital for my outcome as well. How would I `JOIN` that table using the last query you provided? Thanks for all the help and sorry to ask so much, but there's still information lacking from this query.

Comment: The issue with columns from notifications is which rows values to return when you are eliminating the duplicate notifications. My last query does join against users, but concatenates up the values. What would you like done differently with them?